# sendto() sends from the wrong source port

Tags: c++, network-programming

I'm currently working on a networking assignment. We intended the client to automatically get assigned an IP and port to a TCP socket, and bind an UDP socket to the same address and port as the TCP socket. This way, both UDP and TCP share the same IP and port.

I've checked several questions here and all of them seem to state that the source port depends on the address you specify on binding the socket, however, this doesn't seem to work.

This is the code on my client, where I bind the UDP socket:

```cpp
sockaddr_in udpAddress;
udpAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
udpAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
udpAddress.sin_port = htons(27015);

bind(udpSocket, (sockaddr*)&udpAddress, sizeof(udpAddress));
printf("[UDP] Bound to port %d\n", ntohs(udpAddress.sin_port));

printf("Error when binding: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "TEST\n");
sendto(udpSocket, buffer, 7, 0, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
```

When running the application, this prints the following:

```cpp
[UDP] Bound to port 27015
Error when binding: 0
```

Error 0 implies that there is no error, so this should be fine.

However, when I check on the server console, I see the following print:

```cpp
[UDP] 127.0.0.1:64910
```

Which is generated by the following code:

```cpp
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS 
    typedef int socklen_t;
#endif

sockaddr_in from;
socklen_t fromLength = sizeof(from);

short messageSize = recvfrom(udpSocket, (char*)udpBuffer, udpBufferSize, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromLength);

if (messageSize > 0) 
{
    unsigned int from_address = ntohl(from.sin_addr.s_addr);
    unsigned int from_port = ntohs(from.sin_port);

    printf("[UDP] %d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n", from_address >> 24, from_address >> 16 & 0xff, from_address >> 8 & 0xff, from_address & 0xff, from_port);
}
```

I really wonder why this port is invalid. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Also worth saying, it seems like every time I restart my application, the port increments, so I'm not even sure if this is my own fault. If I send a packet to the server using the program PacketSender, the port reported on the server is the same port reported by the program, but this port is assigned automatically, not chosen.

Comment: There is no TCP port neither in the code nor in the detailed description. How is any TCP port related to the question?

Comment: The (WSA)LastError is set when a function fails. You don't check if `bind` has failed. Don't retrieve or evaluate the error code, if `bind` returns 0.

Comment: I was giving the context. The given code doesn't work with a predefined port either, so this is not required in my code snippet. WSALastError doesn't report anything other than 0 anywhere, so even though I should probably wrap it in an ifstatement, it is irrelevant to my problem

Comment: Will check output of bind() once I get home

Comment: And when you do call `WSAGetLastError()`, don't call 95 other functions first. Call it straight after the call that failed.

Comment: Is this all the code? Here, in the first snippet, you're not showing socket creation. Is this code inside a loop or it just finishes after sendto?

Comment: It finishes after the sendto.

Comment: If a piece of code is irrelevant to your problem you should skip it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem. When I tried to check for the return value of `bind()`, I kept getting prompted with an error. It turns out that for whatever reason, I was in the `std` namespace without explicitly stating this anywhere in my own code. After changing `bind()` to `::bind()`, I was able to catch the return value and `bind()` did what I expected.